# Is it possible to get a list of all conflicts?

Tags: couchdb-2.0

I am working on some conflict resolution, and I am running through a test database that has a worrisome number of conflicts.  I am looking for a way to watch a burn down of the conflicts to verify that my script is working.
Is there a way to retrieve a listing of all the document IDs that have conflicts?

I tried things like `https://server/db/_all_docs?include_docs=true&conflicts=true` but this returns everything, conflicted or not.  I just want the IDs of documents that have conflicts, ideally I don't need the conflict revs themselves, just the doc id.

Is this possible?

My other thought, a much more manual process, is to write a script to get all the docs, then loop through all of them, using the get command to get with conflicts, then log them all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing, works decently well.  Would be nice to do this without a script.

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

$username = 'test';
$password = 'test';
$couchServer = 'server';
$dbName = 'db';

$couchDb = new CouchDB($username, $password, $couchServer, 5100);

//getAllDocuments returns the results of this command
//https://server/db/_all_docs?include_docs=true&conflicts=true
$results = $couchDb->getAllDocuments($dbName);

//get all the documents with conflicts
$filteredResults = array_filter($results->rows, function ($value) {
    return isset($value->doc->_conflicts) && count($value->doc->_conflicts) > 0;
});

//convert the class to assoc array
$encodedResults=json_decode(json_encode($filteredResults),true);

//use array column to get all the Ids
$docIds=array_column($encodedResults, "id");
var_dump($docIds);
```

Answer (score 1):

The method prescribed by [CouchDB: The Definitive Guide](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/conflicts.html), is to create a view function such as this:

```
function(doc) {
  if(doc._conflicts) {
    emit(doc._conflicts, null);
  }
}
```